# Objective C SDK in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swiftui, sdk

I consider myself to be a beginner with coding but have slowly been developing an app with Xcode (in swift) and have been trying for the past week to implement survey monkeys SDK, however, the only issue is it is in objective C. You can find the link to the SDK below.

https://github.com/SurveyMonkey/surveymonkey-ios-sdk

I have poured through all the tutorials and research I could find and even have tried to hire someone on Fiverr to help me out but just seem to keep meeting dead ends. The ideal scenario would be if I could somehow implement the objective C code into a struct such as the one below (part61) which is called from a navigation link.

```
NavigationLink(destination: part61(), label: {
 
 }

struct part61: View {

    var body: some View {

   }
}
```

From what I understand, I need to place the objective C code into its own file and connect it to swift with a bridging header but am feeling out of my depth as I am not familiar with objective C and was hoping someone may be able to guide me through the process.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions anyone makes, I really do appreciate it!

Comment: Your problem is probably not so much that their SDK gives Objective C examples; Objective C works very well with Swift. Your problem is that their SDK is written for UIKit and you are using SwiftUI. While you can interoperate the two environments, as a beginner you will probably find it much easier to simply create a UIKit-based project rather than your current SwiftUI project.

Comment: That's a 5-year-old topic.  Where are you having difficulty?  Running a search?  Creating an Objective-C header file?  Using Objective-C methods in Swift?  If you are trying to build Rome overnight, it's not going to happen.